# Uncrustify - trailing comment inside an enum

Tags: c++, c, enums, comments, uncrustify

Is there a way to configure Uncrustify so trailing comments inside an enum won't be automatically moved to a new line?

Meaning, I wish that if I write the following:

```
enum Foo
{
    ITEM1, // this is item 1
    ITEM2, // this is item 2
    ITEM3  // this is item 3
}
```

Uncrusrify won't turn it into the following:

```
enum Foo
{
    ITEM1,
    // this is item 1
    ITEM2,
    // this is item 2
    ITEM3 // this is item 3
}
```

I went over every field and searched everwhere and just couldn't find how it can be done.